# Terminals on Second monitor

Tags: command-line, multiple-monitors, monitor, xterm

I have a HP G62 laptop and a NEC AccuSync LCD73v monitor, which I connect via VGA. I use the terminal a lot, so at startup ubuntu auto-launches 4 Xterms. Is there any way to start them at a specified location? (see images for more clarification)

At startup:
[image: Before]

How I want it:
[image: After]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
gnome-terminal --geometry=AxB+C+D
where,
AxB is the dimension of the terminal
C   is the column number of the pixel in screen.
D   is the row number of the pixel in screen.
```

Thus `12x12+100+200` will create a 12x12 sized terminal with its top-left corner at pixel(100,200).

If the 1st screen is of width 1280, value of C set at 1280 will create the terminal in the 2nd screen.

Comment: woot! Mini Terminal  gnome-terminal --geometry=1x2